# Exibindo mensagem de boas vindas na navbar!

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou fazendo uma aplicação em *MVC asp.net*. Quando o usuário fizer login eu gostaria que exibisse a mensagem de boas vindas trazendo o nome do usuário, contudo está trazendo o email, como altero isso?

O meu action está dessa forma:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Olá " + User.Identity.GetUserName() + "!", "Index", "Manage", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" })
```

Comment: Algumas respostas em perguntas do SO indicam usar o `User.Identity.Name`; já testou?

Comment: Dessa forma da erro indicando que não há nenhum argumento fornecido que corresponde ao parâmetro necessário.

Comment: Está usando Windows Authentication? Ou qual a forma de autenticação do usuário?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você está usando o template do `ASP.NET MVC` com `Identity`, por padrão ele já salva o *Username* com o email informado no método `Register`, veja só:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
        var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
            AddErrors(result);
    }
        return View(model);
}
```

Você pode modificar este comportamento... Como?

Altere sua classe `RegisterViewModel`:

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required,Display(Name = "Username")]
    public string Username { get; set; }


    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }  
}
```

E na `View` `Register.cshtml` adicione o campo que ira receber o `Username`

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Username, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Username, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Feito isso, altere o que o `Username` está recebendo no método `Register` em `AccountController`

```
var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Username, Email = model.Email };
```

E pronto, seu `Username` terá o valor informado, no momento do Registro. =)

Comment: perfeito cara, isso mesmo.. muito obrigado!!

Comment: Só tem um problema, eu faço o registro e da tudo ok, portanto quando saio que tento entrar novamente da tentativa de login invalida!

Comment: @WPfan aí você tem que ver como está sendo feito o login, acredito que pelo email, dê uma olhada no `AccountController` e tente entender o que ela está fazendo no login.

Comment: Consegui, alterei aqui para que requisitasse o nome de usuário e senha ao invés de email e senha, dai deu tudo certo... valeu mesmo!!!