# Fazer login com email e não com username em asp net mvc, como resolver?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Bem, tenho uma aplicação sendo desenvolvida em asp net mvc, na mesma o usuario faz o login e após entrar é exibido a mensagem " Olá fulano, seja bem vindo", para isso eu tive que alterar algumas coisas no meu AccountController, e ai que encontrei o problema, pois não permiti mais após essa alteração que eu faça login usando email e senha, só da certo se eu colocar o nome de usuário e senha, mais a determinação da empresa que o login seje feito apenas com email e senha. Vou mostrar abaixo todos os códigos que envolve esse problema.

Começamos pelo _PartialView:

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Olá " + User.Identity.GetUserName() + "!", "Index", "Manage", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" })
```

Em seguida temos o AccountViewModels:

```
public class RegisterViewModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "O nome completo deve ser informado.")]
        [Display(Name = "Informe o seu nome completo")]
        public string NomeCompleto { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "O nome da empresa deve ser informado.")]
        [Display(Name = "Informe o nome da sua empresa")]
        public string EmpresaNome { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "O número do telefone deve ser informado.")]
        [Display(Name = "Informe o número do telefone")]
        public string Telefone { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "O email deve ser informado.")]
        [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Informe um email válido.")]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "A senha dessa ser informada")]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "A {0} deve ter pelo menos {2} caracteres.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
        [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "A senha e a senha de confirmação não correspondem.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }
```

E no AccountController temos as classe de login e de registro:

```
[HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new ApplicationUser {
                    NomeCompleto = model.NomeCompleto,
                    UserName = model.NomeCompleto,
                    Email = model.Email,
                    EmpresaNome = model.EmpresaNome,
                    Telefone = model.Telefone
                };
                var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);

                    // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                    // Send an email with this link
                    // string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                    // var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                    // await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");

                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
                AddErrors(result);
            }
            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }
```

Aqui a classe de login:

```
[HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                TempData["mensagemErro"] = "Login inválido! Por favor verifique se digitou sua senha ou email corretos!";
                return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
            }

            // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
            // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
            var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);

            switch (result)
            {
                case SignInStatus.Success:
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                    return View("Lockout");
                case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                    return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
                case SignInStatus.Failure:
                default:
                    TempData["mensagemErro"] = "Login inválido! Por favor verifique se digitou sua senha ou email corretos!";
                    return RedirectToAction("Login");

            }
        }
```

Se alguem poder me ajudar com isso ficarei extremamente grato, eu estou no dilema, se exibo o nome do usuario ao invés do email na tela de boas vindas eu n consigo fazer login usando o email e vice versa!!!!

Comment: Dê uma olhada nesta resposta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/271360/exibindo-mensagem-de-boas-vindas-na-navbar/271433#271433

Comment: Essa pergunta minha aqui o contexto é diferente cara.... la eu poderia fazer o login usando o nome do usuário, nesse caso aqui agora sou obrigado a fazer o login com o email, é esse o problema, entendeu???